# Proving Sufficiency Condition for Optimization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have this problem in which I got stuck.
I need to perform the following maximization
$$\max_{x_{1}...x_{N}} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{i}\right)^{\gamma-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} k_{i}x_{i}\right)-\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{i}^{\theta}$$
$$\text{subject to} \quad x_{i}\geq 0, \quad i =1, \ldots, N$$

Where $\gamma \in (0,1)$ and $\theta>1$ and $k_{i}$ are all positive constant. How would you approach the solution of this problem? What I did is find the quantities that solve the first-order condition. Now I need to show that it is a global maximum. Intuitively it is since the positive part would be linear if $\gamma$ was $1$ and the negative part is convex suggesting that the function is strictly concave for positive $x_{i}$. However, I wouldn't know how to be formal with this. I also thought about coercitivity to use Weierstrass but I wouldn't know how to prove it.
Thank you for your precious help.